Captcha does not match error in GEHU-Erp python package
Actually I am working on my personal portfolio site on which I am implementing a system on which all my data shows by fetching it from GEHU-ERP for which I need to login. In this python module if we want to login then we have to call login(Username, Password) first then it calls the captcha() and it takes input captcha and returned to login() but According to my project I first need to render captcha first and send it as argument to login() because I have to make login through form submission on which I need to render captcha first before make login request. Problem is that after  getting captcha image and I take input from form and send captcha code to login function as argument along with Username, Password it always shows invalid captcha and does not authenticate. Please help me to solve this problem by providing solution of this.
Here is code which I modified in client.py file of the module
def captcha(self):
    headers=self.parse_headers()
    print("Headers Value",headers)
    headers["Content-Length"]="0"
    response =self.session.post(f"{self.api}/Account/showcaptchaImage", headers=headers)

    image_bytes = response.text
    print("Image Response: ",image_bytes)

    py_list = ast.literal_eval(image_bytes)

    print("pylist: ",py_list)

    img_data = bytes(py_list)
    print(img_data)

    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
    # print(img)


    # Added by me
    # Save the image
    name = str(random.randint(213366,999999))
    img.save(f"static/Captchas/{name}.PNG")

    # img.show()
    # code=input("captcha code :")
    return name+".PNG"
def login(self,user, password,code):
    data = {
        'hdnMsg': 'GEU',
        'checkOnline': '',
        '__RequestVerificationToken':self.login_token(),
        'UserName': user,
        'Password': password,
        'clientIP': '',
        'captcha': code    # f'{self.captcha()}'
    }
    print("Code is",code)
    data_str = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in data.items()]).encode()



    response = self.session.post(self.api, headers=self.parse_headers(data=data),data=data_str)
    # print(response.status_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    error_div = soup.find('div', class_='validation-summary-errors')

    if error_div:
        error_message = error_div.find('li').text.strip()
        print(f"Login Error: {error_message}")
        print("cause",error_div)
        return error_div
    else:
        self.authenticated=True
        self.student_info()
        config.save_config(headers.SessionId,headers.RequestVerificationToken)
        return response.text

